# Perl Gnokii Script

Tags: linux, perl

Есть скрипт на перл нужна ваше помощи

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# cat sms.pl

`#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use IO::Socket;`

```
my($server, $newmsg,

$max_len, $server_port);
$max_len = 160;
$server_port = 12345;

$server = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort=>$server_port, Broadcast=>0,
Proto=>"udp")
or die "Error starting UDP Server on port $server_port: $@\n";
print "UDP Server started on port $server_port\n";
$newmsg = "";
while($server->recv($newmsg,$max_len)){
if($newmsg){
#my($port, $ipaddr) = sockaddr_in($server->peername);
print "Received: $newmsg \n";
open(GNOKII, "| gnokii --sendsms +79467383638») || die "Starting gnokii     failed: $!\n";
print GNOKII $newmsg;
close(GNOKII);
}
}

die "recv: $!";
```

`root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ./sms.pl`
`Bareword found where operator expected at ./sms.pl line 19, near ""| gnokii --sendsms +79467383638») || die "Starting"
        (Missing operator before Starting?)
Backslash found where operator expected at ./sms.pl line 19, near "$!\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
String found where operator expected at ./sms.pl line 25, near "die ""
  (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 19)
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
String found where operator expected at ./sms.pl line 25, at end of line
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at ./sms.pl line 19, near ""| gnokii --sendsms +79467383638») || die "Starting gnokii "
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at ./sms.pl line 25.`

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: в чём заключается вопрос? уточните, пожалуйста, отредактировав текст с помощью «кнопки» [edit].

Comment: Выдает ошыбку при исполнение скрипта
Bareword found where operator expected at ./sms.pl line 19, near ""| gnokii --sendsms +79467383638») || die "Starting"
        (Missing operator before Starting?).............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

интерперетатор вполне конкретно указывает на «мусор» в этом месте:

```
"| gnokii --sendsms +79467383638»
```

строка текста ведь должна быть выделена одним типом кавычек, а не разными:

```
"| gnokii --sendsms +79467383638"
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное